# Function level authorization authorization keys in azure which mechnisam it is using?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Azure Functions HTTP – Authorization Levels
Function Level comes under which mechanism?

Means is it oauth or anthing else?

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple keys. You pass a key as query parameter on each request. You don't obtain some temporal tokens like you would on oauth.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#authorization-keys

Comment: How can we manage these keys through portal only or any other way?
Is there any way to manage these keys thorugh cdoe(function app)c#?

Comment: Other than portal, this is rest based interface to manage keys
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Key-management-API

Comment: @NarsingRao Really depends on what you mean by managing and what your goals are here. Like, automatically rotate them, secure them for using in other services, add it to ci/cd integration, etc. This is a separate question.

Comment: Rahul gave a possible solution to do that. If you want more info create separate question.